# Python - Can I use cx_Freeze for creating an EEL executable?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am making an eel app, and I finished the html and everything, then I tried to convert the .py file to an .exe file. But cx_Freeze gives the following error:

```py
Trackback (most recent call last):
 File
 "C:\Users\user\AppData\local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__stratup__.py", line 113, in run
 module_init.run(name + "__main__")
 File
"C:\Users\user\AppData\local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 15, in run
  exec(code, module_main.__dict__)
 File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
 File
"C:\Users\user\AppData\local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
   import bottle as btl
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in
  _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in
  _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in
  _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in
  _load_backward_compatible
   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
   File
   "C:\Users\user\AppData\local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 74, in <module>
   _stdout, _stderr = sys.stdout.write, sys.stderr.write
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

It seems the error occurs at the first line, the `import eel` statement.
I don’t want to use Pyinstaller because they are detected as viruses or Trojans.
Should I add some parameters in setup.py, or what should I do?

Comment: From the Help FAQ -- "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ" (Link:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 )

Comment: @JohnAlexINL I was not able to copy the error, that’s why I have posted it as a photo.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I don't think an `eel` executable can be created with `cx_Freeze`.
I have tried with `pyinstaller`, but with `cx_Freeze`, I don't think it would work.